# ROS2: Turtlebot3 tutorial. launch error

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there! I'm using turtlebot3 and i got a problem.

My system is ROS2 Foxy, Ubuntu 20.04LTS

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#gazebo-simulation

In this tutorial, I had installed simulation packages. It was good.

But in the second tutorial that launch the packages, the error occurred.

The error is here

~/turtlebot3_ws$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger

~/turtlebot3_ws$  ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py

**Package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found: "package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/foxy']"**

I think he said "I couldn't find the package!"

so I paste the [turtlebot3_gazebo] package directory into the route where contain packages. [ /opt/ros/foxy/share ].

But same error still occurred.

what is wrong?

thank you : >

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394906/ros2:-turtlebot3-tutorial.-launch-error./) by [Robobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/94528/robobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2022-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed my error.

This was a problem related to the use of the Catkin Package.

It is important to type it's source using the path.

In my case, path is [ ~/turtlebot3_ws/install ]

So type below line in the terminal would be good solution.

> source ~/turtlebot3_ws/install/setup.bash

Have a good day!

---

Originally posted by [Robobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/94528/robobo/) with karma: 36 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1